# Автоматический запуск команд при docker-compose up laravel, npm, composer

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, makefile

Перечитал огромное количество информации по запуску dockera, получилось поднять nginx + mysql + laravel через docker-compose, но суть в том, что приходится это все вручную прописывать и найти исчерпывающий ответ как лучше и правильно сделать автоматизацию я не нашел.
Сейчас развернул докер по данному гайду https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose-ru

Вопрос:
каким образом лучше всего добавить автоматическое выполнение команд, при запуске docker-compose up:
команды:
composer install - для скачивания
создание файла .env(параметры поидее можно получить из docker-composer.yml)
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan make migration

Пробовал и через скрипты .sh и напрямую в докере через RUN писать эти команды, но постоянно вываливаются разные ошибки.

Пример makefile:

build: comp justup dock-comp goup

comp:
    composer install

justup:
    docker-compose up -d

dock-comp:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan key:generate
    docker-compose exec app php artisan config:cache
    docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate --seed
    docker-compose exec app php artisan storage:link

goup:
    docker-compose exec app npm install
    docker-compose exec app npm run dev
    docker-compose exec app npm run watch-poll

upwithwatch: 
    docker-compose up -d
    docker-compose exec app npm run dev
    docker-compose exec app npm run watch-poll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строго говоря автоматизация это не задача докера. В вашем случае докер как инструмент для подготовки и реализации требуемого окружения разработки и RUN это все же не совсем автоматизация, хотя можно и так сказать...   ну не суть.

По поводу автоматизации. Я вот ни разу не говорю про ansible (хотя возможно стоило бы сказать, если бы мы говорили про сложную логику автоматических процессов), но мне  показалось интересным нынешнее использование такого инструмента как make, ну или Makefile, если мы говорим в разрезе задачи.

Например вы можете посмотреть простейший пример вот [тут](https://github.com/maxi-booking/d8base-backend/blob/master/Makefile) , а вот [здесь](https://gist.github.com/iegik/680d6ced994e91f67f100f2893ef83b9)
я для вас нашел как раз ваш пример автоматизации для Laravel и именно через докер. Уверен это именно то что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы мне очень помогли! Сделал небольшой makefile, который собирает мой проект внутри докера и запускает его и все это одной командой make build.